# how to access such a data from the database table in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

**THE PROBLEM I AM FACING VERY PECULIAR.THE VALUES WHAT I WANT IS VISIBLE,WHEN I GET IT AS MESSAGE FROM THE SERVER-WEB CONSOLE. BUT,WHEN I GIVE IT IN FOR LOOP,IT SHOWS ME AN ERROR OF `05-22 18:58:23.203: I/Web Console(29392): JSCallback Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/cordova-2.1.0.js:3727`.
THIS MEANS MY QUERY IS RIGHT.I HAVE COMMITTED SOME MISTAKE IN THE FOR LOOP FOR RETRIEVING DATA.**

I am new to phone gap and using JavaScript to code.I have a doubt and a problem while executing it.I am using sqlite database in  my project.

My table structure will be almost like this

```
id  cid values

1   1   value1
2   1   value2
3   1   value3
4   1   value4
5   2   value1
6   2   value2
7   3   value1
8   3   value2
9   3   value3
```

so I want all the values of the same **cid**,how should I code it?

**My query:**

```
tx.executeSql("SELECT cid,value FROM table where cid="+cid_value, [], querySuccess, errorCB,cid_value);
```

because,when I tried it the following manner,

```
var details = results.rows.length;
console.log("db test value:"+results.rows.item(cid_value).value);
for (var i=cid_value; i<details; i++)
{
cidinstance=results.rows.item(i).cid;
var valueinstance=results.rows.item(i).value;
document.getElementById("s"+i+"cause").innerHTML=valueinstance;
console.log("cid= "+cidinstance +   "valueinstance= "+valueinstance);
}
```

then **when i=cid_value(cid_value=1)** targeting cid=1, where we have four values I get just **3 values**.but,if i put **i=0**,then I get **4 values**

when **i=cid_value(cid_value=2)** targeting cid=2,i get the following

> 01-01 05:45:38.687: I/Web Console(2425): JSCallback: Message from
>   Server: 
>   SQLitePluginTransaction.queryCompleteCallback('1104538538488000','1104538538491000',
>   [{"value":"value1","cid":"2"},{"value":"value22","id":"6","cid":"2"}]);
>   at file:///android_asset/www/cordova-2.1.0.js:3726.

**The Problem is,I am getting the values when I get the message from the server as JS Callback. not from the for loop**

Please,suggest me ways to solve the problem!.guide me to find a way out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this, it should work (I haven't tested it, in case let me know):

```
cid_value = "1";
try{
    tx.executeSql("SELECT cid , value FROM table where cid = ?;", [cid_value], success, failure);
}catch(e){
    console.log("error: "+e.message);
}
this.success = function(tx, results){
    if(results.rows.length > 0){
        for(var x = 0; x < results.rows.length; x++){
            var cidinstance = results.rows.item(x).cid;
            var valueinstance = results.rows.item(x).value;
            console.log("cid = "+cidinstance + " | valueinstance = "+valueinstance);
    }else{
        console.log("results length = 0");
    }
};
this.failure = function(tx, error){
    console.log("error: "+error.message)
}
```

I think your problem is related to the value you initialize your "i" ver in the for cycle. let it start from 0 to get every result of the resultset, instead of a subset of it.

Hope it helps

Comment: yes,you are right.My problem is there. if i put i=0 as you say **it will work only with cid=1 not with the rest of the cid values**

Comment: with my code, if you use cid=2 does it return a resultset with length > 0 (enters the if statement in the success callback?)? does it throw an error?

Comment: it throws an error as `05-22 18:58:23.203: I/Web Console(29392): JSCallback Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/cordova-2.1.0.js:3727`   **When cid=2 and above**

Comment: BeNdErR,any other suggestions? please

Comment: can you double check that you start your for loop from 0? If so, can you repost the updated code? That would be useful to better understand your problem. It seems like you're trying to get a value from a result's index that is not defined (ie: object length = 2, and you want to get the 3rd item in the object)

Comment: thank you, for the answer and especially this comment and these words **can you double check** ...you have helped me...thank you once again

Comment: BeNdErR, I HAVE A DOUBT,I want the application to be opened only once.what should i do to set this. i.e when I move from one HTML page to other I open the DB and only then access the data. **Instead of this,I want to open the database only once and then access it from any HTML Page**

Comment: you should initialize the database for example in a js file that is loaded once the index.html is opened, then you can access the db as you usually do (db.transaciton etc etc).

Comment: BeNdErR,thank you.but,then this is how i initialize in each and every HTML page in javascript. **[like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16709245/can-we-open-2-tables-in-java-script-to-work-in-the-phone-gap-domain)**. IS THIS CORRECT? I SUPPOSE IF THE DATABASE IS DYNAMIC..like as and when the user enters value the application nneds to store the values...in such cases... this will not work