# Can we open 2 tables in Java Script to work in the PHONE GAP domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, sqlite, cordova

I am working in he Phone Gap domain.So,i am new to both Phone Gap and Java Script.

I want to access data from two different tables on the same screen. To make it clear, I want the  **header data** to come from one table say **Table No-1** and the **body data** from another table. say **Table No-2**.

How should i use it?

this is how I am currently using Table no-1.

```
 function onDeviceReady() 
 {    
    console.log("processing onDeviceReady!!! onDeviceReady");   
    var db =  window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase("abc", "1.0", "abc", 1000000); 
    console.log("processing onDeviceReady");
    db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);
 }

 function queryDB(tx,paramName) 
 {
    tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM Table No-1 , [], querySuccess, errorCB);
 }
```

**My doubt is where should I give Table No-2 ?**

**EDIT version--->this is hw i tried implementing:**

```
function onDeviceReady(paramName) 
{     
    console.log("processing Causeee!!! onDeviceReady"); 
var db =  window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase("abc", "1.0", "abc", 1000000); 
    console.log("processing onDeviceReady");
var searchString = window.location.search.substring(1),i, val, params = searchString.split("&");
for (i=0;i<params.length;i++) 
{
    val = params[i].split("=");
    if (val[0] == paramName) 
    {
    return unescape(val[1]);
    }
        value=val[1];
    console.log("valueeesss: "+val[1]);
    cid_value=parseInt(value)+parseInt(1);
    db.transaction(queryDB, cid_value,value);
}
}

function queryDB(tx, results,paramName) 
{
tx.executeSql("SELECT cid,value FROM table1 where cid="+cid_value, [], errorCB,cid_value,value);
    console.log("processing queryDB");
    var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', { 
speed:20,mode:'horizontal'})
var details = results.rows.length;
    for (var i=0; i < details ; i++)
{
    cidinstance=results.rows.item(i).cid;
    var valueinstance=results.rows.item(i).value;
    console.log("cid = "+cidinstance + " | valueinstance = "+valueinstance);
    var val = i;
    var superdiv = document.getElementById('swiper-wrapper');
    var newdiv =  mySwiper.createSlide('div');
    newdiv.append();
    var divIdName = 'swiper-slide'+val;
    newdiv.setAttribute('id',divIdName);
    newdiv.className="swiper-slide";
    superdiv.appendChild(newdiv);
    var cnt = '<div id="container'+val+'" class="container_cause" style="background:url(img/cause_value_bg.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent; "><div id="cause'+val+'" class="clinical_slide"><span ><h5>'+results.rows.item(i).value+'</h5></span></div></div><div class="pagination1"></div>';
        console.log("check value"+cnt);
    document.getElementById(divIdName).innerHTML=cnt;
    console.log("processsing parameter loop ");
}
    ----
 }
```

Comment: i've updated my answer, I totally missed your needs with my 1st one, sorry.

Comment: well,you have answered both my doubts..i will make use of your reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look here

http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2012/4/3/Adding-database-synchronization-to-your-PhoneGap-project

maybe it's useful for you. I think the deviceready should be fired only once, when the device is ready for the first time, and not every time. To check that, try have a look on the console while you browse between different html pages: if this console log

```
console.log("processing onDeviceReady");
```

is shown more than once, there's something you have to change. if is displayed only once, then you are initializing it only one time, and while you browse you only connect to it to get informations.

Hope it helps

--------------edit

Sorry I missed the point of your question With my answer.. Try something like this:

```
function getHeader(){
    db.transaction(function(tx){
        tx.executeSql("select * from table1",[],success,failure);
    }};
    this.success = function(tx, results){
       for(var x=0; x<results.rows.lenght; x++){
           //use resultset from table 1 as you need
       }
       getBody();
    };
    this.failure = function(tx, error){
        //handle error here
    }

}
function getBody(){
    db.transaction(function(tx){
        tx.executeSql("select * from table2",[],success,failure);
    }};
    this.success = function(tx, results){
       for(var x=0; x<results.rows.lenght; x++){
           //use resultset from table 2 as you need
       }
    };
    this.failure = function(tx, error){
        //handle error here
    }

}
```

I haven't tested it, probably I did some mistake, I'm writing from a tablet, and I found out that is not that simple! anyway, the thing is: run your first query , use the results from table number one, and in the success handler call a function that runs the second query. then use the second table resultset as you need.

let me know if it's clear, hope it helps

Comment: 2 PROBLEMS faced...1 it does not accept the codes such as `this.failure` it points it as a error. next when i have given it directly such as `function queryDB(tx, results,paramName) {//my codes with DB}` I get an error such as `05-24 19:20:59.457: E/Web Console(4015): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rows' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/index.html?var%20id=0:57`

Comment: can you please provide a jsfiddle (or update your question code with progress you did so far) with the code that is giving you problem? I need to see your code to find out what's wrong :)

Comment: BeNdErR,sorry for the late reply. wasn't well.please find the edit version.

Comment: no prob! which errors do you get? again "cannot read property 'rows' of undefined" I assume

Comment: yes, this error `05-27 12:17:39.628: E/Web Console(431): ReferenceError: Can't find variable: results at file:///android_asset/www/index.html?var%20id=0:55`

Comment: when there is a semicolon after success() and failure()...it shows an error while the script tag is ending `</script>`.So,i have updated the code in the same fiddle..however I am facing the same error. `05-27 12:55:16.019: E/Web Console(1151): TypeError: Result of expression 'results' [undefined] is not an object. at file:///android_asset/www/inde.html?var%20id=0:56`
`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30673/discussion-between-user-and-benderr)

Comment: BeNdErR sir,1 more doubt..now how to find whether the cid_value of the current object is available or not?? I want to code as if the cid_value is not there in the table1 change the image. **How should I do it?**
I did it like this `if(results.rows.item.cid=='+cid_value'){ //do something } else { //do something }` **but for everything it is executing the else part**

Comment: try if(results.rows.item(x).cid == cid_value){//do something}else{//do something}

Comment: Sir,your help required [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16829761/how-to-implement-search-functionality-in-javascript-for-phonegap?noredirect=1#comment24265209_16829761)

Answer (score 2):

**answer for this question**

```
var db;

function initDb() {
    if(!db)
        db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase("abc", "1.0", "abc", 1000000);
    console.log("db initialized");
}

function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log("processing onDeviceReady");
    initDb();

    try {
        db.transaction(function (tx) {
            tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM table1;", [], query1Success, query1Error);
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error: " + error.message);
    }


}
 function query1Success(tx, results) {
        console.log("query 1 SUCCESS!");
        console.log("results rows 1: " + results.rows.length);
        runQuery2();
    }

 function query1Error (tx, err) {
        console.log("Error: " + err.message);
    }
function runQuery2() {
    try {
        db.transaction(function (tx) {
            tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM table2;", [], quer2ySuccess, query2Error);
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error: " + error.message)
    }

}

function query2Success(tx, results) {
        console.log("query 1 SUCCESS!");
        console.log("results rows 1: " + results.rows.length);
        runQuery2();
    }

 function query2Error (tx, err) {
        console.log("Error: " + err.message);
    }
```

credits to  BeNdErR as well as myself.