# how to implement search functionality in javascript for phonegap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, search, cordova

I want to implement a search functionality in java script.I am new to java script.if i have committed any blunder in the code below forgive me.

How should I implement it?

I tried implementing like this

**javascript**

```
$("#input").keyup(function() {
var userInput = $(this).val();
$("#list div").map(function(index, value) {
    $(value).toggle($(value).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(userInput) >= 0);
});
```

});

**BUT,CORDOVA EITHER DOES NOT RECOGNIZE $...SO WHEN i IMPLEMENTED IT LIKE THIS**

```
document.getElementById("input").keyup(function() {
                var userInput = val();
                document.getElementById("main div").map(function(index, value) {
                document.getElementById(value).toggle(document.getElementById(value).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(userInput) >= 0);
```

**NOW, I GET an error as**

```
05-30 11:59:18.500: INFO/Web Console(930): JSCallback Error: TypeError: Result of expression 'document.getElementById("input").keyup' [undefined] is not a function. at file:///android_asset/www/cordova-2.1.0.js:3727
```

**html**

```
<input type="text" id="input"/>
<div id="list">
<div>Rich</div>
<div>Rajim</div>
<div>vimal</div>
<div>RAGHU</div>
</div>
```

Please,suggest me a solution to work on.

Comment: If you are using `jQuery`,did you include the file?also `var userInput = val();` is really wrong.

Comment: `var userInput = document.getElementById('input').value;`

Comment: @harsha,No i hadn't added the jquery file. Ohh, so what can be substituted for this command `var userInput = $(this).val();`??

Comment: Take a look at my second comment,that shows the substitute for `var userInput = $(this).val();`

Comment: @harsha,nope did not get it..i get the error as `'document.getElementById("input").keyup' [undefined] is not a function.` whereas it works perfectly [here](http://jsfiddle.net/peeter/gAAth/)

Comment: `toggle`,`map`,`text` are `jQuery` methods.Please include `jQuery` in your script

Comment: Add jQuery file and check

Comment: @Napster, No error but functionality is not working!!

Comment: Please post all code. Will be easy to find solution.

Comment: @Napster, please find it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BKf3P/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're not including JQuery. As soon as you include it, it works. jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Y49EW/

```
$("#input").keyup(function () {
    var userInput = $(this).val();
    console.log("here");
    $("#list div").map(function (index, value) {
        $(value).toggle($(value).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(userInput) >= 0);
    });
});
```

To include jQuery:

1) download jquery (choose a version) from here: http://jquery.com/download/

2) add this into the `head` tag of your html page

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-versionyouchoosed.js"></script>
```

For example, if you are using 1.9.1 version, you need to use-

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have added this `<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>`

Comment: No and even the console.log statements between the jquery aren't functioning.BUT after the jquery code its functioning

Comment: is the src path correct? have you downloaded the jquery file? have you imported it before your JS code?

Comment: src is correct.yes downloaded..but i have never used it before.CAN'T WE DO IT USING JAVASCRIPT???

Comment: *capslock* yes you can do it with "vanilla js" if you prefer, but as soon as jQuery offers those functionalities, I suggest to use it, it's easyer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30888/discussion-between-benderr-and-user)